# each loop in coffeescript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, each

I'm new to javascript and starting the mix javascript + jquery + coffeescript all together is not easy for a newbie like me...

I've created a very simple sortable list and I'd like to renumber my list on the fly (the server side code is ok).

The coffeescript code I wrote is:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.simple_grid tbody').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    containment: 'parent'
    cursor: 'move'
    tolerance: 'pointer'
    update: (event,ui)->
      $.post($(this).attr('dataupdateurl') + '/' + ui.item.attr('id') + '/reorder/' + ui.item.index())
      $('tr > td > a > span.number').each (i, element)  =>
      $(element).html i
```

This generates a table of this kind

```
<table class= "simple-grid">
   <tbody dataupdateurl = "xxx">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="some_link"><span class="number">1</span>text 1</a>
         </td>
          <td>
            <a href="some_link"><span class="number">2</span>text 2</a>
         </td>
        <td>
            <a href="some_link"><span class="number">3</span>text 3</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to renumber what's inside the span.number elements when the update callback triggers but I get following error message:

> element is not defined

Any help would be very welcome! Thanks!

UPDATE: the problem was due to the fact that I missed an indent in the last function:

```
$('span.number').each (i, element)  =>
      $(element).html i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know coffee script but generally using jQuery selector doesn't require the full path.
e.g.  `$('tr > td > a > span.number')` could be rewritten as `$('.number')`, also the .each() is generally used as `.each(function(index, element) { YOUR CODE });`. The last thing that looks out of place is setting the html this is generally done as `.html('value')`. So in your case `$(element).html(i);`. Hope this helps?

Comment: Hello, you're right about the selector full path. I changed it. Thanks. About the remaining, I think it's coffeescript syntax equivalent to what you say in javascript. But there is definitely something wrong somewhere...

Comment: If you read the code, logically a post occur and directly after that you do a each. It is possible that due to the sequence of events, the post is done and the dom is not completely created. Try moving the .each fucntionality to a $(document).ready(function(){}); or coffee script equivalent. Thus you know that the script will always execute once the post is completed and the dom was created. It still happens before the render?

Comment: Guess what? The code was ok. It was only a matter of indentation... I discovered this when I moved the code according to your suggestion. Many thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect the actual issue?  It will be good education for others.